# What could I call such nucleic-acid-Sequence? A sort of palindromic sequence? is there any term called mirror repeat?

Tags: bioinformatics, terminology, nucleic-acids

**5'... ATGCC|CCGTA ...3'**

**3'... TACGG|GGCAT ...5'**

or say

**5'... AAGT|TGAA ...3'**

**3'... TTCA|ACTT ...5'**

or in generalised way; on each strand;

**ABCDEF|FEDCBA**

Is there any terminology for such-sort of repeat? A sort of palindromic sequence? A sort of inverted repeat? or mirror-repeat?  Does they really exist in nature? 
(I could not yet found any helpful answer in web, including wikipedia.)

### UPDATE

I asked this question because the term ["palindromic sequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_sequence) is not like the situation in OP [but "palindromic sequence"  is like this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51516/how-to-write-a-palindrome-sequence-as-wish-create-theoretically-self-answe):

5'... ***A*TGCTTTC**|GAAAGCAT ...3'

3'... TACGAAAG|**CTTTCGT*A*** ...5'

or  in general;

5'... *A B C D E F* | M N P Q R S ...3'

3'... S R Q P N M | *F E D C B A* ...5'

Where on single-strand there is no symmetry when read (3'---> 5') and (5' ---> 3').

BUT I'm not telling like that. i'm telling about a situation where a reflection-symmetry present in each **single strand** when read (3'---> 5') or (5' ---> 3').

like

**5'... *A B C* D E F | F E D *C B A* ...3'**

**3'... S R Q P N M | M N P Q R S ...5'**

**From no angle it is a palindromic-sequence because the symmetry is not between 2 opposite strand.**

This question came to my mind when for first- time I'd taught about palindromic sequence. I was unable to "literally" match it with verbal palindromes like "AND MADAM DNA" . Rather it was looking to me like

I EAT CAKE

EKAC TAE I

So I thought, if really there exist any sequence literally like "AND MADAM DNA"... whatever if there is any terminology for it or not.

---

> [One other Q/A site](http://www.answers.com/Q/Mirror_repeats_in_DNA) mentions about a term "mirror repeat", with exact same  situation as OP,  but gave no reference and further biological importance.
>
> > [image]
> >     http://www.answers.com/Q/Mirror_repeats_in_DNA
>
> Latest revision of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Repeated_sequence_(DNA)&oldid=716148908#Other_types) also mentions a term *mirror repeat* and *everted repeat*, but no further explanation and hyperlink is given.
>
> Another result from google search.
>
> > [image: https://s3.amazonaws.com/classconnection/27/flashcards/2952027/jpg/mirror_repeat-14FB21C6EBF540D2120.jpg]
> >     URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/classconnection/27/flashcards/2952027/jpg/mirror_repeat-14FB21C6EBF540D2120.jpg

Comment: I found some links in web, but some are  about other-topics based on DNA-symmetries, and some (those giving a direct  definition or  terminology) contain too-little information and no reference, like this:  http://www.answers.com/Q/Mirror_repeats_in_DNA

Comment: I'm wondering so-many websites used the term "mirror repeat" exactly in same meaning as I asked !!!! but none reaches to origin of the term. https://quizlet.com/11685525/chapter-8-slides-flash-cards/ , https://o.quizlet.com/o4SEbpAdTIwyIgNv6uLjMA_m.jpg fig 8-18 , https://www.studyblue.com/notes/note/n/nucleotides-and-nucleic-acids/deck/15240912,  (not readily accessible) https://s3.amazonaws.com/classconnection/27/flashcards/2952027/jpg/mirror_repeat-14FB21C6EBF540D2120.jpg (google image search result)

Comment: Another  from google search: http://slideplayer.com/slide/5171943/  .   Page 54/65.  URL:   http://images.slideplayer.com/16/5171943/slides/slide_54.jpg

Comment: The last attached image (from google image results) helped me  proceed a further lot because there are lot of articles in web about "Hoogsteen structure". Here is one.http://ase.tufts.edu/biology/labs/mirkin/documents/1995AnnRevBio-Mirkin.pdf

Comment: "a related arrangement is mirror repeat, in which the inverted repeat sequence is non palindromic. These sequences play important roles by showing or blocking protein synthesis by the ribosome- a process called transcription attenuation (see chapter 18)-or forming recognition sites for restriction enzymes" https://books.google.co.in/books?id=HmUdBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA191&ots=TKF0OiYsAa&dq=biological%20significance%20of%20hoogsteen%20structure%20mirror%20repeat&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q=biological%20significance%20of%20hoogsteen%20structure%20mirror%20repeat&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the situation you showed should be called *mirror-everted repeats*: to my knowledge they occur very rarely, and I only found references in [this](http://www.microbiologyresearch.org/docserver/fulltext/micro/150/11/3519.pdf?expires=1473711148&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=AF342F9027E85EB1DF16CA272D824C36) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923250899001163) articles, even though no graphic explanation is provided.

Comment: No? I did not find them same.

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Sorry about that, just updated my answer.

Comment: Don't worry patterns are always tricky and almost whole of  biology is about patterns.

Comment: @ Roberto The links you gave wasn't helpful because first one (http://www.microbiologyresearch.org/error/authentication;jsessionid=1f6fbsnhjmcl.x-sgm-live-03) shows page doesn't exist, and second one (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923250899001163?np=y) tells to buy (right-now which is not being possible, sad for that) and its preview contains no diagram, so you could provide some diagram etc. from these articles, I'll be grateful

Comment: No. the second article is not free-access.

Comment: I've let you know the second article is *Not* free access.

Comment: @ Roberto Preste Since the portion of your answer before the update isn't correct, if you kindly modify that-portion; I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The term:

> [‘reverse tandem **repeat**’](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2879273/)

has been used by a few authors, but the Google search engine retrieves only 28 instances, of which no more than 20 are unique.

There are about three times as many hits for:

> [‘reverse tandem **duplication**’](https://glosbe.com/en/en/reverse%20duplicate)

which would be a more precise term in the current instance.

Comment: To whoever made the original entry. Answers in SE Biology should be written as answers not rhetorical questions, and supported by evidence or argument. That is why I edited this answer, discovering a more common term courtesy of Google's autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

As an example of biological symmetry, with my tongue in my cheek, I would call this a [**mirage**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mirage).

My reason is that from a structural point of view a sequence of the type you present:

```
5'... ATGCC|CCGTA ...3'
3'... TACGG|GGCAT ...5'
```

does **not** have **mirror**-image symmetry. This lack of symmetry is because of the asymmetric nature of the phosphodiester bond. The 5' and 3' in your diagram clearly illustrate this fact (3' is not the reflection of 5' either typographically or structurally) If you don’t follow this, draw out each phosphodiester bond in the sequence halves. The base order in the second half may mirror that in the first half, but the directionality of the phosphodiester bonds is the same.

This is not just pedantry but explains why (or is consistent with) such structures appear to have no importance in biology and hence no name. (One only gives names to things one needs to refer to.) One would not expect such structures to occur frequently as they can not be generated by duplication (inverted or not). Those that do occur by chance lack symmetry and would be no more likely to bind proteins than any other sequence (symmetrical DNA structures apparently lending themselves to protein-recognition).

I imagine one could describe such structures in a mathematical sense and give them a name, but if that is your question it should be migrated to a different SE.

Comment: No not exact in mathematical sense... but rather was finding biological occurrence.  I can't confirmedly say there is no biological importance... one i've read about such a sequence in certain biochemistry text... but then I was in hurry situations... I forgot to note-down that . Later-on I could not recall where I've read that.  I yet think this question is properly about biology.

Comment: Thanks yes it is not about mirror-image of stereochemistry. It is just about genetic sequence.

Comment: If anyone don't know about a thing, how they can start conclude like "it has no importance", or "off-topic" or such. I agree I don't know that is why I am doing a question. But when a professional user doesn't know about a thing yet hurry to decide an action... it really wonders me. (wrote for every moderator, not any specific one)

Comment: @AlwaysConfused — You asked "Does they really exist in nature?" so a comment on their biological importance was a valid reply. It was not a suggestion that your question was unimportant. I had tried to answer your question from a biological perspective, but felt it possible that you were still interested in the logical aspects. In the latter case I felt it more likely that mathematicians or people interested in language would be more likely to be able to answer your question. Migrating it to another SE group is not rejecting it, just helping you find the appropriate audience.

Comment: Its ok but google search showing me, many source telling about such sequences, and even with same terminology (though none of them directs to proper source). Even another user posted an answer. Then a statement "such structures appear to have no importance in biology and hence no name. " was quite surprising. I wished  to keep the question in biology, but if you still think some-other site like maths or chemistry could give better answer, let me know.